# ReactNative FlatList react-native-swipeout performance issue

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

When the data count is 100, flatlist renders the record by batch as follows 0 to 10, 0 to 20, 0 to 30, 0 to 40 .... 0 to 100. So it took around 20 sec to render all the rows.

Issue1: During this time I could not perform swipe right action (ie I could not perform swipe action till all(100) rows are rendered).
Issue2: Also i could see swipe performance lagging(ie swipe animation response is very slow) when i add the code line 'extraData= {this.state.activeRow}' to the Flat list. On re-rendering the flatlist due to the state change in activeRow, I could not perform another swipe action till all 100 rows are rendered.

```
< FlatList data={this.state.data} renderItem={this._renderRow} extraData= {this.state.activeRow} />

_renderRow({item, index}){
let swipeBtns = [
  {
text: 'Edit',
    backgroundColor: '#5DAE5D',
    underlayColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1, 0.6)',
 },
];

return (
    <View>
        <Swipeout right={swipeBtns}
          close={(this.state.activeRow !== index)}
          rowID={index}
          sectionId= {1}
          autoClose = {true}
         backgroundColor= 'transparent'
          sensitivity = {20}
          onOpen = {(secId, rowId, direction) => this.onSwipeOpen(rowId, direction)}
          onClose= {(secId, rowId, direction) => this.onSwipeClose(rowId, direction)}
          >
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text>Sample Test</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </Swipeout>
    </View>
);
} 

onSwipeOpen(rowId, direction) {
    if(typeof direction !== 'undefined'){
        this.setState({activeRow:rowId});
    }
}

onSwipeClose(rowId, direction) {
  if (rowId === this.state.activeRow && typeof direction !== 'undefined') {
      this.setState({ activeRow: null });
  }
}
```

Kindly suggest solving Issue1 and Issue2 to improve the swipeout performance with flatlist.